# how to make this code keep asking a number until finds a prime number?

Tags: java

I would like to have some ideas on how I can make this code to keep asking for a number until the program finds a prime number. Thank you so much :)

import java.util.Scanner;

```
class SieteDosEjerSeis {
    
       public static void main(String args[])
       {        
        int temp;
        boolean isPrime=true;
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        //capture the input in an integer
        int num=scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();
        for(int i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
        {
               temp=num%i;
           if(temp==0)
           {
              isPrime=false;
              break;
           }
        }
        //If isPrime is true then the number is prime else not
        if(isPrime)
           System.out.println(num + " is a Prime Number");
        else
           System.out.println(num + " is not a Prime Number");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Place the code inside a `while` loop: `while (!isPrime) { ... your code ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Well, mainly what everyone said, you need a Loop that stops when the number typed in the scanner is a prime number.

In this case I would say is better to have another method to check if N is prime or not, for a cleaner code.

**✓ Tested**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SieteDosEjerSeis {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean prime = false;
    
        // loop until prime is true
        while(prime == false){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            int n = s.nextInt();
            s.close();
    
            // is it prime?
            prime = isPrime(n);
    
            if (prime){System.out.println(n + " is a prime number.");}
            else{System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number.");}
        }
  }
  
  // method that returns true or false depending if N is prime or not
  public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
           if (num <= 1) {return false;}
           for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
               if (num % i == 0) {return false;}
           }
           return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally somebody notices to loop to `sqrt(n)` instead of `n/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the prime evaluation to a new method:

```java
class SieteDosEjerSeis {
    public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
           if (num % i == 0) {
              return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }    

    // ...
}
```

Then, change your IO code to be based on the result of this method:

```java
class SieteDosEjerSeis {
    // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            if (!isPrime(num)) {
                System.out.println("The number is not prime!");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        // This will only be reached if the number is prime
        System.out.println("The number is prime.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **do while** loop for this.

```
class SieteDosEjerSeis {
    
       public static void main(String args[]) {        
           int temp;
           boolean isPrime=true;
           do {
              Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.println("Enter a number:");
              //capture the input in an integer
              int num=scan.nextInt();
              scan.close();
              for(int i=2;i<=num/2;i++) {
                  temp=num%i;
                  if(temp==0) {
                     isPrime=false;
                     break;
              }
              //If isPrime is true then the number is prime else not
              if(isPrime)
                  System.out.println(num + " is a Prime Number");
              else
                  System.out.println(num + " is not a Prime Number");
           } while (!isPrime);
        }
    }
```